# Make symlink on Windows of whole tree without modifying the original folder

Tags: windows-8, symbolic-link

I'm trying to do this: make a symlink of a whole directory "C:/Master", in different folders like "C:\Projects\Alpha\", "C:\Projects\Beta\" an so on.

"Master" directory usually changes in files and data. I work on the "Projects/*", where every project folder uses the "Master" files, but every one has new files in them. Let's say, I point to the car engine in every project folder, and inside them I add different kind of wheels.

The problem I'm having, as a Windows 8 user, is that symlinks (junction) acts as a window to "Master" - I'm not allowed to add any file inside. I looking a way to reference the entire "Master" directory, and add new files - not edit any of the "Master" ones.

It's as [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/596733/is-it-possible-to-create-a-subfolder-inside-a-symlink-folder-but-not-be-added-in), but on Windows.

Comment: The answer to the question you reference is to use hard links instead of symlinks (and to link all the files, rather than the directories). Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the other team adds and combines files at daily basis, so I have to copy and paste all files every time a change is done, or before work on it, in every Project folder. Its time consuming.